# rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte & sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
im begginer and have installed ROS 2 or 3 days ago , i have some problems:

1. when i type `rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte`  i received the answer : `rosws: command not found`,
2. and when i type :  `sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall`, i received the answer : `Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing`? i dont know what should i do to complete my installation
   so please guide me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217585/rosws-init-%7E/fuerte_workspace-/opt/ros/fuerte-&-sudo-apt-get-install-python-rosinstall/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To 1:

This indicates that you don't have the `rosws` on your `PATH` or not installed. Due to your second question, I assume the latter.

To 2:
Is this actually the only error message? If so, have you tried what it says there, i.e. have you tried to update your package definitions with
`sudo apt-get update`? Then try to install again with `sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall`. This will most probably fix the issue.

On a side note: Fuerte is a **VERY** old ROS distro by now. I would suggest to start with ROS Indigo (if you want an LTS version) or ROS Jade (for the latest one). If you are stuck on Ubuntu 12.04 for whatever reason, at least try ROS Hydro... (and then, after Fuerte, there was even another one: Groovy. So with Fuerte you are actually behind by 4(!) releases and you will NOT receive any updates!)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0